# PHP/PEAR database-to-oop mapping engine?

Tags: php, oop, nhibernate-mapping, mapping, pear

last week I have spend on creating a dynamic DB-to-OOP mapping engine in PHP.
It works pretty well. You define your DB, make PHP classes with same names, call one method, it generates the SQL, fetches the result, and creates the appropriate objects from it.

You can apply different query filters, it automatically joins parent tables, translation tables (for multi-language db), value tables (which don't have classes on PHP side), it has a build-in filter validator (so only valid sql are passed to the db) etc. etc. etc.

It is nothing revolutionary, but with some careful table/class naming it gets the job done pretty well.

Later on, I opened my cPanel and had a look at PEAR modules, and I can see there are many modules that deal with databases. I'm new to PEAR, haven't used it before.

Can anyone tell me if there is a module that does something similar, like I described above?
Just to make things clear, I'm not looking for a proxy generator, which will generate the code for the classes, but a dynamic mapper, which does everything pretty much *on-fly*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.doctrine-project.org/ Is this what you're looking for? An ORM?

Answer (score 0):

[Pear::DB](http://pear.php.net/package/DB/)?

Comment: Maybe, still reading. Hate this pear documentation. Anyway, I'm looking for something that can handle dynamic filters. For instance, in my engine, I just write $users=User::getAll(array("cityId=2", "age>18")), and it gets all users from city 2 older that 18. I don't want to write the sql for getByCity, getByAge, getByCityAndAge separately

Comment: I'd also take a look at Zend::DB. I personally hate the pear system. Zend is managed actively by a company, is licensed fairly, and actively maintained.

Comment: Anyway, should I even look for another solution, or should I stick with what I got? Mine is working pretty well. I just thought a widely used, published, one should be more optimized, and probably a little faster and better polished

Comment: It's kind of up to you. The benefits of an open, widely used, system si that you dont have to maintain it. However, if you aren't sure it is worth the benefit of doing so now and want to get your application to launch (yes, please), then I'd wait until you get a hair up your ass.